# UIViewController doesn't rotate sometimes?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I want to let our viewController to rotate according the iPad's orientation. so I override the method

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true }
```

while sometimes it didn't work, like this situation, I put the iPad landscape orientation, everything is normal, then I log out my account, which will reset window's rootViewController be login view controller, while the login view controller is portrait orientation, which is wired, if I press home button, go back to home screen, the re-enter my app, everything will be normal again, it will be landscape.
so does you guys know what causes this?  thanks a lot.

Comment: I think , this case related to device.

Comment: @whitekevin : have you restricted screen orientation for specific view controller or to `rootViewController` itself?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, no, this issue happens when you set your view controller  directly to be rootViewController,